# NSLabel: pointer arithmetic?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I allocated a number of labels and now I am trying to update the text in each one.
However the I am not sure if the pointer arithmetic is correct or if I need to keep track of the address in another variable array and reset label to it??  The app keeps dropping out after the NSLogs...

```
[lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]]; // <--- drops out here
```

Code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        NSLog(@"pointer arithmetic");
        NSLog(@"pointer: %d", lbl);

        lbl++; // <--------- pointer increment to write to next object

        NSLog(@"pointer increment: %d", lbl);

        [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];

        [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", kk ]];

        kk++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `*lbl set...`? That will dereference the pointer and give you the object it points to, which is what you need to access its methods and properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure you can count on Objective-C to create objects with sequential memory addresses. In other words don't do this.

Just make some arrays to hold your labels and iterate through those.  Then you dont have to manage memory addresses at all and the code is *far* easier to read and understand.

Comment: ya, I was afraid it may not be contiguous, but was unsure if objective-c made up for it.  I put it on the stack(with an array) but maybe I should just create a double pointer and put on the heap to be safe ??  It works on the stack.

Comment: I would argue that when dealing ObjC objects and methods, it's rarely good to be manually messing with pointers or creating double pointers.  Unless your goal something weirder than your code snippet implies, all you need is to put labels in some arrays and then iterate trough those arrays.  Anything else is more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @Kristen: you shouldn't even use a C-array of Objective-C objects, like `UILabel *x[10]`. Just use `NS(Mutable)Array*`.